# Adding expected calls in a loop

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest, googlemock

This is what I want to achieve. In my test fixture I want  to call a helper functions with a parameter `n` to tell the test fixture how many initialization sequences should be expected. Some parameters used in the sequences are stored in three `std::vector` containers; `fileDescriptor, handle, selectionObject`.

What I have written is this:

```
void MyTest::init_Ok(uint32_t n)
{
  for (uint32_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
  {
    fileDescriptor.push_back(i); // FDs starting at 0
    handle.push_back(reinterpret_cast<void*>(18 + i)); // handles starting at 18
    selectionObject.push_back(555 + i); // SOs starting at 555

    EXPECT_CALL(MyMockApi::getApi(), initialize(Pointee(nullptr), StrEq("InitString"), MyMatcher()))
      .WillOnce(DoAll(SetArgPointee<0>(handle[i]),
                      Return(INIT_OK)));
    EXPECT_CALL(MyMockApi::getApi(), selectionObjectGet(handle[i], Pointee(nullptr)))
      .WillOnce(DoAll(SetArgPointee<1>(selectionObject[i]),
                      Return(SELECTION_OK)));
    EXPECT_CALL(MyMockApi::getApi(), finalize(handle[i]))
      .WillOnce(Return(FINAL_OK));
  }
}
```

I know why it's not working. It is expected that all calls to `initialize` will be identical but yet I want to perform different actions (parameter depending on loop counter `i`) for the first, second, third, ..., nth call. The current implementation will only expect one call to `initialize` no matter parameter `n`. Is it possible to fix this and keep it a loop somehow, or do I have to add the actions with a `WillOnce` line for each `i`? This would mean i have to check `n` and add different number of `WillOnce` lines for different possible values of `n`, which i really want to avoid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way could be to use `Invoke`. You can write a function which will have access to the handles container and a running member/static variable(lets say counterVar) which will indicate the number of times the function is hit. Based on the value of counterVar, you can decide the logic.

```
.WillRepeatedly(Invoke(<your function>))
```

Something like:

```
EXPECT_CALL(MyMockApi::getApi(), initialize(Pointee(nullptr), StrEq("InitString"), MyMatcher()))
      .WillRepeatedly(Invoke(successfulInitialize));

ReturnCode successfulInitialize(void* op, std::string msg)
{
   static int counterVar = 0;
   *op = handles[counterVar++];
   return INIT_OK;
}
```

Comment: @MartinG, I know this a old post but I have the same problem now. How did you solve it?